# socket.io vs pusher, which one is better to use with laravel

Tags: laravel, socket.io, node-modules, pusher, pusher-js

i am just new into this concepts about sockets and i am so confused.Firstly i found that i can use pusher for realtime messages but it limits concurrent connections 100 and number of  messages to send..then what about socket.io, does it have some kind of limitations? From what i have researched i assume it has no such limitations as pusher but i want to be sure.can anyone explain me how socket.io can do this, i mean if socket.io have no such limitations why would pusher be even used with payment plans?

Comment: Laravel comes with pusher examples, so it is easiest to use... Build your test scenarios with pusher and than try different socket vendors like socket.io...

Comment: thanks yes now i am moving to socket.io but just wanted to know if it had any downsides like no. of concurrent connections...because i couldnot find those info anywhere

Comment: Remember that, there are also, other nice engines, like ably.io for example... Have fun coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get the same limitations with socket.io however it can be a little daunting to set it up, I found this introduction on laracasts really useful when I was looking into it - https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io/episodes/1